# How to add styles to angular component? (every second element)

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a question about adding styles to Angular components.
e.g I would like to have every second angular component in a list to have red background-color.
How can I make it happen?

I tried a lot of different things - it seems that it is added in HTML but doesn't work.

```
<ang-component class="someClass" />
<ang-component class="someClass" />
```

I tried setting it in parent component styles

```
ang-component:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: red;
}
```

but it doesn't work. It shows up while inspecting but there is no visible effect

EDIT: Code - to show an example how it looks

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="someParentClass" (ngSubmit)="onUpdateForm()" >
    <item></item>
    <hr />
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
<hr />
<div id="btn-save-section">
    <button class="cancel-btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button class="update-btn" type="button">Update</button>
</div>
```

I want item components to change - so every second should have background color red

Comment: You can have a look at [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). You can't style a `component's selector` via HTML adding a class to it. Instead you can achieve it by targetting the selecetor in a style's file. For example: `ang-component {font-size: 1rem;}`.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I tried different options with nth-child()
So lets say that I have a parent component template. Should I declare this nth-child() in a parent component style's file? Then I can set `ang-component:nth-child(odd): background-color: red` right? It doesn't work for me

Comment: I've made you a simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/TheBrickSlayer/pen/PoQPBZm)

Comment: And also a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjy9v1?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: .container > ang-component:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
 }
Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ang-component:nth-child(odd) > * {
 background-color: red;
}
```

because your component root element is probably only a container w 0 width and 0 height

[image]

Comment: Still the same, doesn't work :(
`
ang-component:nth-child(odd) > * {
  background-color: red;
 }
`

Comment: can you share the rendered markup of one of your components? This would make it easier to debug. FE component frameworks usually wrap components with CSS to reset the component style.

Comment: Markup - but without css - https://codepen.io/Proth7/pen/XWZmBQb
Nothing is added on the component level - then inside the item there are styles: 
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

Comment: in the code pen you just shared, if you repeat the markup (<item...>) then add this css: item:nth-child(odd) .image-item {
  background-color: #f00;
} it will display your desired outcome. I was hoping the same to happen in the real world, but if it does not, you'll have to thoroughly inspect your component's css once its rendered in the browser, in order to figure out what is overriding your new selectors / rules.

Comment: Added this 
item:nth-child(odd) .image-item {
  background-color: red;
 }
in the scss file - still nothing

Comment: works with fonts - doesnt work with background-color. Such a weird thing...

Comment: Added the codepen outcome to the answer. Assuming that you're still not getting the desired outcome, I cant really advice any further without getting more details on the context, you'll have to (Ill say it again) thoroughly inspect your component's css once its rendered in the browser in order to figure out why the style isnt kicking in, or being overriden by some other, more specific selector. Another thing you could try would be to increase your new css selector specificity: html > body ang-component:nth-child(odd) > * { background-color: red !important; }

Comment: when you inspect the element inside the component that you want to change the background color, what dimensions (box size) do you get? and what css rules does it display? Because maybe you're trying to set the background color of an hidden element (either hidden by its dimension, visibility, opacity etc...)

Comment: when I try to inspect it it says the width dimensions of the container and height of 100px BUT that is a little weird because when I hover on the element in Elements view it shows only the tooltip with dimensions - doesn't show the area with padding etc

Comment: ok so that hints us that the element you're trying to colorize isnt visible. 3 options now: 1.trying to figure out why and make it visible (probably a bad idea since it is made invisible for some layout specific reason); 2. trying to set the background color of some other element in the component that fills the area, maybe adding a pseudo-selector to your component style. 3: wrap each component inside a div and set the background color of the div wrapper instead.

Comment: thank you for help. I will try to debug why it happens. Yeah - I mean I know that wrapping it can be done but it looks bad, maybe I will try to figure out something else

Comment: Setting display:block fixed the issue - somehow it was not displayed at all